# How can i use Java.sql.Connection in a different android activity?

Tags: java, android, jdbc, database-connection

I'm trying to create a little android app.
My problem is that one: After creating a JDBC Connection to my DB in the first Activity, how can i use the same connection in other activities to make querys?
I know how to make the query with the statement, but can i pass the connection of the Main Activity in order to use only the first connection in all the other activity of the application?

My db is AS400 of the IBM and i can access to it only with JDBC (in the Android platform). I know that is simple with web service but the company want to make everything in this way.

Sorry for my english, i'm an Italian guy!

Comment: `Connection` is a regular Java object, so you can pass it along, e.g. using `Intent.putExtra()`

Comment: i tried without good results. I've searched on the net all the day!

Comment: In that case you may want to show your code, the results you got (explaining why they weren't "good"), and results you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not a problem to use your DB in many components simultaneously. If you use common pattern of your DB-class to encapsulate standard `DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` - you can instantiate your DB class in many Activities and it will be used in thread-safe mode.

```
public class DB {
    private static final String TAG = "DB";
    public static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 7;

    final DBhelper mDBhelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DB ( Context context ) {
        mDBhelper = new DBhelper(context);
        // open the DB for read and write
        mDB = mDBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public synchronized long insertSite ( objSite s ) {
        ...
    }
    ...

    private class DBhelper
              extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBhelper ( Context context ) {
            super(context, C.DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate ( SQLiteDatabase db ) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.d(TAG, "entering onUpgrade(): oldVersion="+oldVersion+", newVersion="+newVersion);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And use it as usually

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DB eventsDB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        eventsDB = new DB(this);
        ...
        eventsDB.insertSite(objectSite);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can't use this example because my db is AS400 of the IBM and i can access to it only with JDBC (in the Android platform). I know that is simple with web service but the company want to make everything in this way. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Khm... Why did you hide this significant detail earlier? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

In Android usually you use SQLite to persist your data. Try this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

If you have a database server and you want to access throw an android device, i suggest you to wrap database access with an intermediate server which expose data with web service (REST).

You don't specify if database access is in internet or intranet context, so i thought it is in an mixed context.

Comment: I have an AS400 database (IBM) and the simplest way to use it in Android is to use JDBC (I think). The database is very big, i'm working for a company. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Don't use Android device as client jdbc. I suggest you to use an intermediate server and connect android device to database throws web service (REST).

Comment: Yes @xcesco, but i'm not able to create the server side of the web service. It's the first time for me. Can you help me? There is a service online where i can put the Server side Code? Thank you!

Comment: You can try with Google Cloud Platform (https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial?_ga=1.191676266.1116869860.1460053636&pli=1)